# How can each item in a Yii listbox show not only text but an image as well?

Tags: listbox, thumbnails, yii, listboxitem

I am trying to have a listbox showing the friends a specific user has. However, i want each listbox item to show not only the name of the friend, but a thumbnail sized picture.. How could I implement this? I have been searching for some kind of item template option, but no luck. I also searched for a special htmlOption that could be used, but couldnt find one in the source code. Right now, my code only shows the names:

```
echo CHtml::listBox('listOfFriends_id','',
CHtml::listData($model->friends, 'id', 'name'),
array('onclick'=>'SelectedPosition()'));
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) to fully customize the HTML for your list. To make it show a drop down menu, you would:

- Set `tagName` to `select`
- Set `itemsTagName` to `option`
- Set `enableSorting` to `false`
- Set `enablePagination` to `false`
- Set `template` to `"{items}"`

I 'm probably forgetting a few more other variables you need to tweak, but the idea is that `CListView` provides total customization of the HTML for the list so you can get it to make a drop down.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was indeed very helpful, now i am facing a [new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322382/how-can-i-update-yiis-clistview-when-a-new-record-was-added-triggered-by-an-ajax), your opinion is more than welcomed! :) Thanks again