# How can I update Yii's CListView when a new record was added triggered by an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, listview, yii

Yesterday I was introduced to the CListView and could manage to display all the information i want about my records, and in the format i want. I have a 'create' button (add a new contact), which opens a modal pop up window with the corresponding fields. When this window is closed, i return to the CListView, and here is my issue: i've been trying to update the CListView (without any luck, clearly).

I believe it should be easy to update the clistview with this call: $.fn.yiiListView.update('*CListViews's ID*'), but i can't find the proper event that should trigger this call.

Next, i post what i would think is the relevant code:

**Button**

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton ("Create",
                          CController::createUrl('/contacts/create'),
                          array('onclick'=>'
                                    $("#createContact").dialog("open");
                                    return false;',
                                    'update'=>'#createContact'), 
                          array('id'=>'showCreateContactDialog'));?>
```

**CListView**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($model->contacts, array('pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>5,),)),
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'emptyText'=>'empty',
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", 
    'pagerCssClass'=>'page-number',
    'id'=>'ajaxListView',
));?>
```

Any help is more than welcome!! Hope this helps someone eventually as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is finding what to trigger the `CListView` update with (the JS update snippet you provide should work fine).

Probably the [jQuery dialog event close](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close) is what you are looking for; it will get triggered after the dialog has been closed. Alternatively, there is also a `beforeClose` event that has the additional capability to prevent the dialog from closing.

Comment: In the end i changed completely the approach and ended up using json encoded data, but i got to implement your suggestion and it worked just fine, so thanks!!